# Vs Code Scratch and Production Org credentials are the same (can't pull sources from production)

Tags: production, org, source

I'm working in a collaborative training, and created a scratch org, and then tried to open in another window the production org to track changes. The thing is, that both orgs have the same credentials, and VsCode linked them (when clicking "Auth an Org", it shows production and scratch as a same enviroment I guess). When I create a new proyect and try to get the Production org sources, it fetches only the scratch Org ones. I may have set the default org as the scratch one, but can't change it from the execute commands (ctrl + shift + p) because it shows all aliases together as a same environment... Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot have the same Salesforce internal user credentials on two or more orgs.

Comment: You should perhaps try to re-auth production using the sfdx CLI.

Comment: Well... you can auth an Org and a DevHub with the same user:password in VsCode...

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have the dev hub on that same org?

Comment: Well it is the same org. It has production and then I enabled the DevHub in the same salesforce page to create a Scratch Org from there to code. In VsCode I authorized the production org in a window, and authorized the DevHub org in another one. Then got the sources from production and tried to sync the changes in the production VsCode window. Then got into troubles with authorizing the production org to pull the codes...

Comment: Use `sfdx force:org:list` to check the state of your authorised connections. You may need to re-authenticate one or other of them or reset an alias. Your scratch org and prod org will have different credentials. Your dev hub IS your prod org from what you said. Verify that your aliases still align with what you thought you set up.